# Member function pointer issue with standard library methods

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, standard-library, pointer-to-member

This question is spawned from
[Passing a member function pointer to an overloaded class method into a template function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31309846/passing-a-member-function-pointer-to-an-overloaded-class-method-into-a-template).
You need not read that to understand this question. Probably both the questions will have the same answer.

I am getting [compiler error for below simple code](http://ideone.com/wJvaxn).

```
#include<set>
template<typename Return, typename T>
T ReceiveFuncPtr (Return (T::*Method)(const int&))
{
  T obj;  // Found and declared an object of actual container class
  (obj.*Method)(1);  // Some processing
  return obj;  // Returned that container class object with RVO
} 
int main ()
{
  ReceiveFuncPtr(&std::set<int>::insert); // ERROR
}
```

The error is interesting:

```
 In function 'int main()':
error: no matching function for call to 'ReceiveFuncPtr(<unresolved overloaded function type>)'
   ReceiveFuncPtr(&std::set<int>::insert); // ERROR
                                        ^   
note: candidate is: 
note: template<class Return, class T> T ReceiveFuncPtr(Return (T::*)(const int&))
 T ReceiveFuncPtr (Return (T::*Method)(const int&))
   ^   
note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
note:   mismatched types 'const int&' and 'std::initializer_list<int>'
   ReceiveFuncPtr(&std::set<int>::insert); // ERROR
                                        ^   
note:   mismatched types 'const int&' and 'std::set<int>::const_iterator {aka std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<int>}'
note:   mismatched types 'const int&' and 'std::set<int>::const_iterator {aka std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<int>}'
note:   mismatched types 'const int&' and 'std::set<int>::value_type&& {aka int&&}'
note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'Return'
```

If you look at the *note*s closely then it appears that compiler is matching all the other methods except the right one! In this case compiler should have matched `insert(const std::set<int>::value_type&)` aka `const int&`. If I change the `ReceiveFuncPtr()` to match some other overload, it will again fail by skipping that overload.

To debug this situation, I created handcrafted version of `std::set`. But that [compiles fine](http://ideone.com/ioNWD3):

```
template<typename T, typename T2 = void>
struct MySet
{
  std::pair<T,bool> insert (const T& i) { return std::pair<T,bool>(T(),true); }
  std::pair<T,bool> insert (T&& i) { return std::pair<T,bool>(T(),true); }
  void insert (std::initializer_list<T> i) { return false; }
}
int main ()
{
  ReceiveFuncPtr(&MySet<int>::insert);  // OK
}
```

After surfing, I came across this post:
[What are the rules for function pointers and member function pointers to Standard functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13521030/what-are-the-rules-for-function-pointers-and-member-function-pointers-to-standar)

Though it's related , it doesn't solve problem.

**Question**: Why member function substitution fails in case of standard library method when the the same thing passes for handwritten class method?

**Update**:

After looking at the correct answer, I am sure that `insert` cannot be used. The only way would be ugly typecasting which is an overkill for this problem.
One elegant **solution** is to use `std::set<int>::emplace<const int&>` which has only `template`d version unlike insert which has mix of `template` and non-`template` versions.
Call the function as below:

```
ReceiveFuncPtr(&std::set<int>::emplace<const int&>);
```

Above [compiles fine](http://ideone.com/ps4PJb).

Comment: it actually compiles and work well on MSVC with visual studio 2013 : `template <class T, class Ret>
T exec(Ret(T::*func)(const int& i)){
 T t;
 (t.*func)(4);
 return t;
}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem isn't with the `insert` functions you showed in `MySet`. The problem is with one of the ones you omitted. Specifically:

```
template< class InputIt >
void insert( InputIt first, InputIt last );
```

From [temp.deduct.call]:

> When P is a function type, pointer to function type, or pointer to member function type:
>   — If the argument is an overload set containing one or more function templates, the parameter is treated
>   as a non-deduced context.

Since [`&std::set<int>::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert) is precisely such an overload set, the parameter is a non-deduced context and cannot be resolved. Your example of `MySet` does not contain a function template overload for `insert`, which is why it works fine. If you add one, you'll see that it will also fail to compile.

Comment: Yes, with adding a `template` function it [doesn't compile](http://ideone.com/SF5EbB). I skipped that function, thinking it to be irrelevant for this example :-). It would be a bonus, if you can come up with an elegant solution for the actual problem, i.e. how to implement `ReceiveFuncPtr()` with this constraints.

Comment: @iammilind You'd have to cast it to the right type. In this case, that's a mouthful: `ReceiveFuncPtr(static_cast<std::pair<std::set<int>::iterator, bool> (std::set<int>::*)(const int&)>(&std::set<int>::insert));` Or you could write a class with no such function template `insert`.

Comment: I have updated your answer with a possible solution, which I am going to use now. To use `emplace()` function. Hope you are ok with it. :-)

Comment: @iammilind `emplace` works because you explicitly provide the right function, not because it's only templated.

Comment: @Barry, that's correct. My perception is: In case of `emplace`, we don't have to do ugly typecasting like how we have to do for `insert`. Just 1 extra `template` argument has to be added. In short, I am thinking from "clean looking" perspective.